# Android new folder issues

Tags: android

Ok, so have 2 Activities in my app, that will do some stuff.
In the mainActivity before I start the second Intent, I want to create the necessary folders for my app to work correctly.

So, my code so far looks like this:
In the main activity I use this code to create my folder on the SD card, before starting the new intent :

// on click of a button

```
createWholePath(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(),"test");
```

// and the function

```
public static boolean createWholePath(String mainfolder, String subfolder){
    boolean ret= true;
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+mainfolder+"/"+subfolder);
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    return ret;
}
```

In AndroidManifest I added the permission like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now I expect to see a folder created (on the device's SD card) after I click the button
But it does not happen...
What could be wrong?
Why doesn't the folder appear?

I use for debugging a real device *(Samsung Galaxy Note 2)

Thank you

**UPDATE**
So my problem was part of a bigger project and something went wrong somewhere else apparently. I decided to make a new empty project just to test my code and yes, it works fine outside my original project. I will investigate further. I will award the answer to the guy that tested my code and said that it works

**Thank you all.**

Comment: are you getting any error then check your log cat  and just debug

Comment: before create Folder you have to check whole path, is correct or wrong. And try this one ret = wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
check return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't working? Your code is working for me (after I replaced the spinner value with a constant string). Perhaps the directory is being created, just not where you're expecting it. You can see where the directory will be created using a line like:

```
Log.v(TAG, "wallpaperDirectory=" + wallpaperDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it could be your method is not called on spinner item selection

```
  spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {


            try{


                Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                createWholePath(item.toString(),"test");

            }catch(Exception e){}
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: It was not that. I was calling it in the right place

Answer (score 0):

```
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),mainfolder+"/"+subfolder);

                        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
                            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
                        }


    and put these permission to manifiest :-
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```